# Ewhile using javascript variable with EJS ERROR post is not defined

Tags: javascript, ejs

if i use the var "postContent" in the second paragraph tag i get this error

but if i directly put in
`post.content.substring(0,50)` in the paragraph tag it works for some reason

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<p> <%= content %> </p> 

% let postContent = post.content.substring(0,50); %>   

<% postStorage.forEach( (post) => { %>
 <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
 <p> <%= postContent + " ..." %> </p>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: What is `Ewhile`? Please post the exact error including the traceback in the question.

Comment: What does the data look like in the `post` object? What is `postStorage`? If there is already a top-level object called `post` then don't use that name for the variable inside the `postStorage.forEach` loop. Use something else like `forEach( (storagePost) => ` etc.

Comment: Did you want the substring to be inside the loop? If it's per-post it needs to be where there's a `post` available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `postContent` inside the loop.

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<p> <%= content %> </p> 

<% postStorage.forEach( (post) => { 
 let postContent = post.content.substring(0,50); %>
 <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
 <p> <%= postContent + " ..." %> </p>
<% }) %>
```